# ListView items not deleting when I return to the main screen

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to reset my `ListView` so that the remaining calories and total would be cleared when an image button is clicked. I tried deleting the `ListView` items, which worked, but when I came back to the activity the items are still displayed.

```
public class FragmentHome extends  Fragment implements 
              View.OnClickListener  {

    private TextView caloriesTotal;

    private TextView caloriesRemain;

    private ListView listView;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;

    ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
    ImageButton ResetEntry;
    Context context;

    int goalCalories;
    int totalCalorie;

    //Database
    private DatabaseHandler dba;

    private ArrayList<Food> dbFoods = new ArrayList<>();
    private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
    private Food myFood ;

    //fragment
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    public FragmentHome() {
     // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);

        AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(4);

            }
        });

        ResetEntry = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.ResetEntry);

        ResetEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //reset data
                reset();
           }
        });

        caloriesTotal = (TextView) 
        myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);

        caloriesRemain = (TextView) 
        myView.findViewById(R.id.calorieRemain);

        listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);

        SharedPreferences prefs = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),   
            R.xml.activity_preference, false);

        goalCalories = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", "2000"));  

        refreshData();

        return myView;
    }

    public void reset () throws SQLException {

        if(foodAdapter!= null) {
            foodAdapter.clear();
            dbFoods.clear();
            listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);// !!!!!!!
            listView.invalidateViews();

            foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void refreshData (){

        dbFoods.clear();

        dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();

        totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();

        int CaloriesLeft = 
            loadPrefs("\"@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount\""
            ,totalCalorie);


        String formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
        String formattedRemain = Utils.formatNumber(goalCalories - totalCalorie);

        //setting the editTexts:
        caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories);
        caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);

        SharedPreferences prefs = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), 
            R.xml.activity_preference, false);

        goalCalories = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", "2000"));

        //Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){

            String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
            String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
            int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
            int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

            Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

            myFood= new Food();
            myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
            myFood.setFoodName(name);
            myFood.setCalories(cal);
            myFood.setRecordDate(date);

            dbFoods.add(myFood);
        }
        dba.close();

        //setting food Adapter:
        foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),  
            R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
            listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
            foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   //save prefs
   public void savePrefs(String key, int value) {
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putInt(key, value);
       editor.apply();
   }
   //get prefs
   public int loadPrefs(String key, int value) {
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
       return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, value);
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
       String username1 = username.getString("Username");

       TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);

       userMain.setText(username1);
   }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
      super.onDetach();
      startActivity( new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.AddItems:
              AddEntry addEntry = new AddEntry();

              fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
              fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
              fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,addEntry).commit();
              break;

          case R.id.action_settings:
              Intent preferenceScreenIntent = new Intent(getContext(),
              PreferenceScreenActivity.class);
              startActivity(preferenceScreenIntent);
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleting from ListView is not the same as deleting from the database

Comment: I was able to get it to work. What I had to do was delete the items from the database and refresh the adapter which worked

Comment: Good to know. You are welcome to answer with your solution below, if you would like.

Comment: Thanks will do . this is my first time on stack overflow

Comment: Welcome, then! Make sure you go over some of the topics in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about asking (and answering, if you would like).